# Get Integers form a String using streams (Java)

Tags: java, string, integer, java-stream, extract

I'm currently working on a task where I'm supposed to program a very simple "chatbot".
The goal is a public int method, that gets a List which contains questions as a parameter.

Each question may or may not contain numbers and depending on which numbers the chatbot ist supposed to answer differently. I dont know in advance if and how many numbers will exist but it is safe to assume that they will be in integer value range. I also need to create an average number if there are more than one in the same question.

Now I will need to extract all different numbers with streams and then reply acordingly.

A question may Look like this: "Will there be 14 or perhaps 27 mails in my office today?"

Now I need a way to extract all numbers form all questions from that list seperatly into e.g. an array using a stream. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish that? Lines of code doesnt realy matter. It should be quite fast and I need to use a stream as in java.util.stream for reasons.

Comment: Okay. Now what is your question?

Comment: Excuse me if I havent made that clear. What the best method is, to extract an unknown number of integers from a string in e.g. an array, without mashing them together with a stream.

Comment: There are at least 2 distinct problems here (and therefore one question each...). First, how to extract integers from a string, then how to transform data using Java stream API. I also think you'll certainly find answers to both problems by simple googling.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the actual question. Also "best" to vague since it depends on the underlying metrics. Fastest? Least memory-footprint? Most readable? Least lines of code? Least characters? ...

Comment: Sorry, my first post, I'm trying to correct it above.

Comment: I'm sadly quite a beginner as you probably already have noticed. How do I use this pattern on a List<String>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.OptionalDouble;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Will there be 14 or perhaps 27 mails in my office today?";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (m.find()) {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for (int n : list) {
            sum += n;
        }
        System.out.println("Average: " + sum / list.size());

        // Using Stream
        OptionalDouble average = list.stream().mapToDouble(a -> a).average();
        System.out.println("Average: " + (int) average.getAsDouble());

        // Another way of doing it using Stream
        int sumInts = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
        System.out.println("Average: " + sumInts / list.size());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Average: 20
Average: 20
Average: 20
```

**Update:** posting the following update to do it without using any loop:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.OptionalDouble;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Will there be 14 or perhaps 27 mails in my office today?";
        String newStr = str.replaceAll("[^-0-9]+", " ");
        List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(newStr.trim().split(" "));
        List<Integer> list = strList.stream().map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // One way
        OptionalDouble average = list.stream().mapToDouble(a -> a).average();
        System.out.println("Average: " + (int) average.getAsDouble());

        // Another way
        int sumInts = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
        System.out.println("Average: " + sumInts / list.size());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Average: 20
Average: 20
```

**Another update**: posting another update as per your request in the comment

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Will there be 14 or perhaps 27 mails in my office today?");
        list.add("There are 40 candidates competing for 4 places");
        list.add("There are 6 teams each with 4 different channels");

        System.out.println("Numbers in each string:");
        list.stream().map(s -> Arrays.asList(s.replaceAll("[^-0-9]+", " ").trim().split(" ")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
                .map(lst -> lst.stream().map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("Average of numbers in each string:");
        list.stream().map(s -> Arrays.asList(s.replaceAll("[^-0-9]+", " ").trim().split(" ")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
                .map(lst -> lst.stream().map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .forEach(lst -> System.out.println(lst.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum() / lst.size()));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Numbers in each string:
[14, 27]
[40, 4]
[6, 4]
Average of numbers in each string:
20
22
5
```

Comment: Hi Arvind, thank you for your answer. Sadly my task contains, that I need to use a stream to do so and I'm not allowed to use any other kind of loop e.g. while, for.

Comment: Thank you very much. And how could I creat that List of Integers from the List of Strings using a stream instead of a while loop?

Comment: Your update is gold and thank you so much for the effort. I just have one more remark. I already have a List<String> as a parameter so str above is just one of many questions in that List that I need to stream through and get the Integers out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your effort. This help me a lot!